# Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I$ and ideal of $R$. How can I prove that $(I^e)^c=\{a\in R\mid (\exists s\in S)\,sa\in I\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I$ and ideal of $R$ and $S$ a multiplicative subset of $R$. Consider the natural morphism $\ell:R\to S^{-1}R$. Here the extension $I^e$ of an ideal $I$ of $R$ is defined in two ways:

$I^e:=S^{-1}I$ and

$I^e:=\langle \ell(I)\rangle\in S^{-1}R$.

The contraction $J^c$ of an ideal $J\subseteq S^{-1}R$ is just the preimage by $\ell$.

With all this is mind, how can I prove that $(I^e)^c=\{a\in R\mid (\exists s\in S)\,sa\in I\}$?

I already proved $\supseteq$ (just notice that $\frac{sa}{s}=\frac{a}{1}\in S^{-1}I$) but I can't prove $\subseteq$. This comes form Exercise V.4.9 from Algebra: Chapter 0.

Comment: So how did you prove $\supseteq$? This would be very useful to see here for the context.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\in (I^e)^c\implies \;\exists\;\frac is\in S^{-1}I\;\;s.t.\;\;\ell^{-1}\left(\frac is\right)=x\iff \ell x:=\frac x{s'}=\frac is\iff sx=is'\in I\implies$$

and we're done. If we assume $\;1\in S\;$ we can take $\;s'=1\;$ in the above and it is slightly simpler.

Comment: Thanks! Great comment. It was pretty easy, bad for me :(

Comment: @FranciscoGallardo Good answers are upvoted and accepted. Can you do this?

Comment: I can't upvote any of my answers, and the only one that can ever accept an answer is the person who asked the question...

Comment: @DonAntonio Can you see to whom is my comment addressed?